# jquery validation Plugin - control custom range textboxes overlapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

```
lower: {
    minlength: 1,
    maxlength: 4,
    required: true,
    digits: true,
    between: ['#pLower', '#pUpper']
},
upper: {
    minlength: 1,
    maxlength: 4,
    required: true,
    digits: true,
    greaterThan: '#lower',
    between: ['#pLower', '#pUpper']
},
pLower: {
    minlength: 1,
    maxlength: 4,
    required: true,
    digits: true,
    between: ['#lower', '#upper']
},
pUpper: {
    minlength: 1,
    maxlength: 4,
    required: true,
    digits: true,
    greaterThan: '#pLower',
    between: ['#lower', '#upper']
}
```

---

I have two custom functions from which one greater then is working fine but checking overlapping between the both ranges is an issue for me. If have to check the first two textboxes between the bottom ones and bottom ones with the first. So if top ones have 1 and 50. it will not allow to write 25 and 75 in others.

---

```
$.validator.addMethod("greaterThan", function (value, element, param) {
    var $min = $(param);

    if (this.settings.onfocusout) {
        $min.off(".validate-greaterThan").on("blur.validate-greaterThan", function () {
            $(element).valid();
        });
    }

    return parseInt(value) > parseInt($min.val());
}, "upper must be greater than lower");

$.validator.addMethod("between", function (value, element, param) {
    var $min = $(param[0]);
    var $max = $(param[1]);

    if (this.settings.onfocusout) {
        $min.off(".validate-between").on("blur.validate-between", function () {
            $(element).valid();
        });
    }
    return parseInt(value) < parseInt($min.val()) || parseInt(value) > parseInt($max.val());
}, "values must not overlap");
}
```

---

http://jsfiddle.net/walidmalik/4ERP7/